# SQL Query to replace character based on join

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called service entry which has a field called part description. I am trying to normalize my table structures.

**Dbo.ServiceEntry

```
  ServiceEntryID, Description
     1200         270 ~ Syringe assembly  ~ 7,3 ~ Increase drive current from 3 --> 1.|282 ~ LPH pcb ~ 8 ~  | 287 ~ Valve block
   assembly ~ null ~
```

**Sample data for the part description column:**

**270 ~ Syringe assembly  ~ 7,3 ~ Increase drive current from 3 --> 1.|282 ~ LPH pcb ~ 8 ~  | 287 ~ Valve block
   assembly ~ null ~

In the above here is the structure for the column:
**PartID ~ PartDescription ~ ServiceType ~ Comment**

For multiple parts, this character **|** is added and the structure is repeated.

Now the other table **Service Entry Part** has a one to many relationship for instance a Service Entry could have multiple Service entry parts.

```
Dbo.ServiceEntryPart
ID,ServiceEntryID,PartID,Comment,ServiceType
```

New Update to the table ServiceEntryPart will contain a column called Part Description. so it will look like below

```
**Dbo.ServiceEntryPart
ID,ServiceEntryID,PartID,Comment,ServiceType,PartDescription**
```

Existing Data in ServiceEntryPart:

```
ID  ServiceEntryID  PartDescription PartID  ServiceType Comment
1    1200                            270      7,3        Increase drive current from 3
2    1200                            282      8          
3    1200                            287      null
```

Desired Data in ServiceEntryPart

```
ID  ServiceEntryID  PartDescription  PartID    ServiceType   Comment
1    1200           Syringe assembly    270      7,3         Increase drive current from 3
2    1200           LPH pcb             282      8          
3    1200           Valve block         287      null
```

So essentialy for the sake of normalization, I want to look at the existing service entries and within the description column, I want to parse out the part description and update the service entry part table with the appropriate part descriptions.

Comment: Where does `~ L0 ~ P0` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Stop thinking about storing a description in a single variable and updating each row one by one. SQL Server is optimized to work on sets; so think about applying an update to all rows at once. Note that I made a guess about where `L 0 ~ P 0` comes from (hard-coded). If this is something real, please include that information in the question.

```
UPDATE se SET PartDescription = STUFF(
  (SELECT '| ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), p.ID) 
       + ' ~ ' + p.Description + ' ~ L 0 ~ P 0 '
    FROM dbo.Part AS p 
    INNER JOIN dbo.ServiceEntryPart AS sep
    ON p.ID = sep.PartID
    AND p.OldPartID = sep.OldPartID
    WHERE sep.ServiceEntry = se.ID
    ORDER BY p.ID FOR XML PATH, TYPE
  ).value('.[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM dbo.ServiceEntry AS se;
```

Comment: 5000 ~ New Slide Description ~ 7 ~ Increase drive current from 3 --> 1.| 5500 ~ Xyz ~ ~ 8 ~  | 5510    so in this column the first 5000 is the id and the description new slide description is the part description. so for each part im just trying to update the id and part description

Comment: @user19096 ugh.

Comment: Im sorry,I updated the question. Would you think I should add the column part description in the serivce entry part table. And then based on the existing records populate that column

Comment: Yes, you should build up the information in the concatenated column completely with all the information you have RIGHT NOW. Or better yet, don't store it there, just create a view that puts it together at runtime, then you don't have to update this again tomorrow or next week when more parts change. Your application isn't going to care when the concatenation happened...

Comment: so if i try to update part description column in the normalized service entry table, atleast once I have to populate it manually and in the future the app code will populate that column. so for this data 270 ~ Syringe assembly (piston and barrel) ~ 7 ~ Increase drive current from 3 --> 1.| 282 ~ LPH pcb ~ 8 ~ | 287 ~ Valve block assembly ~ 8 ~ | 290 ~ Syringe assembly (piston and barrel) ~ 7 ~ Increase drive current from 3 --> 1    How could I update the existing service entry part table with the part description which is the after the first ~.

Comment: Wow that is very hard to read and follow. Could you read your comment and tell me, honestly, if you didn't write it, you'd be able to make any sense of it? Please don't put a bunch of display junk in a comment. Unreadable. As for your question, I don't know, I have a hard time reading your tabular data too. Does my update statement (or something quite derivative) not help? What first `~` are you talking about? There are MANY of those in your question.

Comment: I agree, I will update my question with what I meant in my previous comment. If that would make it clear and you have a suggestion then great, otherwise I will mark your answer as correct anyway.

Comment: I updated the question. Sorry about earlier. Hopefully its clear now.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. The very first output shows `270 ~ ...` but the table has two columns. So is it `270` | `~ ...` or something else? If it's in one column, what value is in the `ID` column for that row?